# Shiny R Histogram

Tags: r, shiny, histogram

I am using below code to lean Shiny R , when i run this code, it gives me this error:

> Warning: Error in hist.default: 'x' must be numeric
>     [No stack trace available]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Ind","Indipendent Variable",choices = names(mtcars)),
  selectInput('Dep','  Dependent Variable',choices = names(mtcars)),
  plotOutput("BoxPlot"),
  plotOutput('Hist'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data1 <- reactive({input$Ind})
  data2 <- reactive({input$Dep})

  output$BoxPlot <- renderPlot({boxplot(get(data2()) ~ get(data1()) , data=mtcars)})

  output$Hist <- renderPlot({hist(get(data1())}) 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

any help why would it say so ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try not to put everything into 1 line as it doesnt improve readability, you can use [Google's R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml) if you like.To answer your questions you can access the variable via `[[]]` like so:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Ind","Indipendent Variable",choices = names(mtcars)),
  selectInput('Dep','  Dependent Variable',choices = names(mtcars)),
  plotOutput("BoxPlot"),
  plotOutput('Hist')
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data1 <- reactive({
    input$Ind
  })
  data2 <- reactive({
    input$Dep
  })

  output$BoxPlot <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(get(data2()) ~ get(data1()) , data=mtcars)
  })

  output$Hist <- renderPlot({
    req(data1())
    hist(mtcars[[data1()]])
  }) 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Pork Chop, great suggestion. it worked, but quick question , whats the difference between [] and [[]]

Comment: The double brackets are for accessing variables inside more complex objects such as lists, you can read more in this nice blog https://davetang.org/muse/2013/08/16/double-square-brackets-in-r/ and also in the manual
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing

Comment: awesome , and why do we need req function ? I also noticed that we used it for the histogram , but not for the boxplot , why so ?? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Using `req()` is just a habit of mine, which I think is a good practice to get into, you shouldnt need it here unless you're dynamically generating content

Comment: @Fahadakbar Probably also worth pointing out that the reason it wasn't working in the first place is because `get(data1())` was being translated to, for example, `get("mpg")`, which returns the entire `mtcars` data frame. As a result, you were originally calling `hist` on the data frame, and not on the specific variable. This answer gets around that by calling the variable directly from the `mtcars` dataset.